# NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'toJson'

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit, dio

I get `NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'toJson'.` error after I've changed some API requests.

I've already tried to rebuild .g files multiple times.

Example of service:

```
  @GET("/api/payments/income/{ref}/ultimate")
  Future<IncomePaymentActualDetailsResponse> getIncomePaymentActualDetails(
    @Path("ref") String ref,
    @Query("uetr") uetr,
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in defining `uetr` param. You need to specify variable type the next way `@Query("uetr") String uetr,`

then generate files `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`